# Finding the number of partitions of logical truth over an operator.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, propositional-calculus, generating-functions

How many ways can I break up a logical expression and combine them over the XOR operator to be the equivalent expression?

For example, let A and B be the operands.

There is only one way to get A AND B, that being (A AND B).

There are two ways to get A XNOR B, those being (A XNOR B), and that of ((A AND B) OR (not A AND not B)). That is, we have one the possibility of doing it with one operator (XNOR), or with two expressions over an operator (OR)

From my calculations, there are 5 ways to get A OR B, those being (A OR B), (B OR (A AND not B)), (A OR (B AND not A)), ((A AND B) OR (A XOR B)), and ((A AND B) OR (A AND not B) OR (not A AND B)).

If I'm right, there are 20 ways to get (A TAUTOLOGY B) = 1 e.g. one way is ((A XOR B) OR (A XNOR B)).

It seems as if this is something like somehow breaking down the expressions into sets of N unique sub-expressions, for example, if N = 4, then (3+1), (2+2), (2+1+1),and (1+1+1+1), but the 3 and 2 can also be broken down to 3 = (2+1) and (1+1+1), and the 2 can be broken down to (1+1). Not sure if this is a useful approach or how to start creating a sequence or possibly a generating function.

Comment: what is XNOR ? Is it the **"equivalent"** operator : A XNOR B iff A and B are simultaneously true or simultaneously false ?

Comment: This sounds potentially interesting but is currently unclear to me. What does it mean to combine logical expressions "over" an operator? In your first example, How is "(A XNOR B)" a way of "doing it with one operator (XOR)" (since there's no XOR in that expression)? And why is "with two expressions over an operator (OR)" a relevant example when you wanted to count the ways of doing it "over the XOR operator"?

Comment: @JeanMarie, that is correct.

Comment: @joriki great catch, indeed, it should have been XNOR not XOR. Also, "over" an operator means using that operator to operate on the operands e.g. A XOR B would be A and B over XOR (note the and is not the AND). Or in another way (A,B) over XOR. As for the third inquiry, I want to count the non-overlapping ways of doing a calculation, so XOR would be one way, or the expression can be broken down further, but instead of using XOR, a combination of 1 OR and 2 AND operators can be used. Actually it might be a little more clear with a paper I put out in which I show operators can be represented -

Comment: - by matrices and that these matrices can be broken apart which basically allows for using other operators in place. The paper is here: https://www.b-theory.com/CorrespondenceMatrices.pdf